# Show the custom view in window in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm showing a normal ViewController. Now i will tap on a button and all i want to see is like the following image:

[image: My Custom View interaction]

In this image, the background is my root view controller and when i tap on the button, an image view that include black color(alpha = 0.8) will put on top and show my Custom View. In my Custom View, when i tap on DONE button -> the content of textField1 and textField2 will send back to rootViewController and hide my Custom View.

So, could you please help me for solve my situation? Tks in advance.

Comment: What have you done till now?

Comment: I just need a solution or an sample project, no need to sample code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the delegate & block programming to send the data back to the root View Controller.

Comment: Im stucking in the textfield. When i tap on textfield, the keyboard not show and i got exception.

Comment: Can you please let us know the exception which you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, In Interface builder, Add a UIImageView to the view, and a UIView and connect them both to your .h file. Then set the imageView's values and buttons in custom view and And in your viewwillappear method in .m file, set them hidden using `[imageView setHidden:YES];`

And when you want to show them just set your setHidden to NO and you should be able to see the customView.

Comment: Please read my situation again, im not just want to show a simple custom view. I also want to take control on it and pass data back to rootview controller

Comment: yes so…? simply you add textFields on that customView, connect them to your .h files and then when you display the customView get their values and pass it wherever you want..

Comment: I have created class CustomView already, set delegate and in my RootViewController i call `self.view addSubView:CustomView`. Through the delegate, i can pass data but now i get stuck in my textField, it not show when i tap on it.

Comment: now theres a change in the question u asked.. :) Ok have you connected them to the .h file?